# load testing with jmeter and latency in tomcat

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, jmeter, load-testing

I have a simple load testing scenario in our environment in AWS. The application is a 3 tier with apache(ec2), tomcat(ec2) and mysql (rds in aws) as database with load balancers in front of apache and tomcat. We are trying to load test with jmeter that has 500 threads at a ramp up time of 10 seconds. The http request is a simple call to our application that takes an input and returns the same as output.
apache is configured as a simple proxy pass and tomcat is configured as follows:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"       acceptCount="100" minSpareThreads="250"  maxThreads="400" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1"/>
```

Here is jmeter response:

summary +      1 in 00:00:05 =    0.2/s Avg:  1565 Min:  1565 Max:  1565 Err:                                                                       0 (0.00%) Active: 98 Started: 211 Finished: 113

summary +    499 in 00:00:10 =   52.3/s Avg:  1319 Min:    51 Max:  3916 Err:                                                                       0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 500 Finished: 500

summary =    500 in 00:00:14 =   35.5/s Avg:  1319 Min:    51 Max:  3916 Err:                                                                       0 (0.00%)

When you invoke the URL from a REST client, the time taken is 100-200ms. When we invoke 500 requests in 10 seconds, the performance drops significantly as above. I added one more tomcat server to the load balancer with no improvements.

I took thread dumps when executing the load test and i see that lot of threads are in RUNNABLE state as follows:

```
"ajp-bio-8009-exec-120" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f23680fe000 nid=0x4d1b runnable [0x00007f2341594000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.read(AjpProcessor.java:309)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.readMessage(AjpProcessor.java:364)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:128)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
```

tomcat is running with 2-4GB of heap and jmeter is running with 1GB heap. apache and tomcat is dual core, 7.5GB instance of AWS(m3.large).

Apache is configured in preform MPM as follows:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       150
MinSpareServers    100
MaxSpareServers   150
ServerLimit      350
MaxClients       350
MaxRequestsPerChild  10000
</IfModule>
```

I dont see any latency in cloudwatch of AWS in Load Balancers. 
I am at a dead end. Any pointers ?

Comment: Perhaps with many threads, but only dual core, a thread starts (RUNNABLE state) but then has to wait for the CPU.

Comment: cpu is never running at high percentage in top command. So i doubt it is cpu. will try with a larger instance in aws with quad core.